# Why can't Monroe track his own wife?

Tags: grimm

In Season 5 Episode 3, "Lost Boys", of *Grimm*, Rosalee is taken by

> a group of orphaned *Wesen* who want her as a foster mother. Monroe uses the previous foster mother's scent to hunt them down.

Why can't Monroe track Rosalee by her scent instead?

Comment: Considering that it **is** his wife, and they live together, wouldn't he just be covered in her scent anyway? That might make tracking her difficult.

Comment: Not in the slighest. In the show we clearly see Monroe pick up her scent immediatley and without difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

The children used a truck in the abductions. 
Vehicles don’t leave a scent trail of the occupant(s), so Monroe would have been able to track Rosalee’s scent from the shop
(where she was grabbed) to where the truck was parked — not very useful. 
He then would have been able to track her scent trail from the truck to the kids’ hideout —
but the truck was in the woods, near the hideout,
and the good guys didn’t know exactly where that was. 
(And even those are questionable, if Rosalee was carried,
and her feet didn’t touch the ground.)

The significance of the previous foster mother is that
she ran from the hideout to the road, where she was found (which was a known location). 
Therefore, Monroe was able to track her scent from the road back to the hideout.

Comment: Makes sense. Altho we have seen Monroe track Wessen before just by sitting in a car and sticking his head out of a window. If I recall he was tracking some Wessen that lived deep in the woods and drove a car to get from A to B.